# Flex/Spring: Working with join table/entity

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, flex3, spring, blazeds

I have a question regarding mapping and entities/domains with Flex/Spring mapping via BDS. I currently have domains mapped to tables, and I am working off existing code to try and change the logic from web services to work with Blaze.

Now, i came across a value object used previously that mapped to a datagrid, but that value object wasnt a true table entity. Now I split that value object into two logical ones, MessageItemFormats and MessageItemTypes. Now, that it is split, i have to find a way to work with both of them at the same time. I have a datagrid in the view that maps as a dataProvider to the valueObject. How do I map it to a split set of domains?

I am new to hibernate/Java, so I am not sure how this works from the Flex site of things... How do I join them to get attributes from both entities?

Comment: Are you asking how you update the Flex UI to use a nested object model rather than a collection of objects with simple property types (String, Number, Date, etc)?

Comment: OK. Let's say I have two objects, MessageItemType, MessageItemFormat, and I have a datagrid that I previously used to map to just MessageItemFormat, but now I split that into the two objects mentioned (the properties that is). Now I need to have my datagrid take the joined/combination of those two objects.